# Xamarin.Forms: close DatePicker in code, when custom renderer is used

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I have a custom [`DatePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker), which is opened if the user taps on it. It uses the same mechanics like the [Xamarin.Forms DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datepicker?view=xamarin-forms). The scenario is like the following:

- user taps on the custom `DatePicker`
- instead of picking a date he opens another dialog
- two dialogs are now opened at the same time

I tried to [`Unfocus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.unfocus?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_Unfocus) if the other element get's the focus, but nothing happens. The `DatePicker` is still displayed.

What else can I do? Should I throw manually the `Unfocus` event? Can I lock the UI somehow so that the user has to press the *Finish* button before moving on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the issue doesn't occur if I switch between `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`. It only occurs if I switch from `DatePicker`/`TimePicker` to my `Entry` (which triggers a custom dialog in `Focused` event).

And `Unfocus()` does work, if you do it on the UI thread:

```
private async void someEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        this.datePicker.Unfocus();
    });
    // custom dialog shown to user ...
}
```